# consistent rendering of css3 filter

Tags: google-chrome, css, filter, safari, webkit

I was just about to do some fancy css3 filter things on my website, but sadly the browsers show completely different results.

Because filters are only available to webkit browsers so far ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)), I've experimented only with `-webkit-filter` so far.

The problem is, that Safari (tested on iOS) interprets `brightness(0)` as default value and `brightness(1)` displays the element full-bright.
Chrome has a default value of *1*.

Is there a way to achieve a consistent brightness for webkit browsers?

See this jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4SMDf/1/

Thanks in advance,
McFarlane

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a SVG filter.

Here's an example:

```
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="brightness">
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncR type="linear" slope="[amount]"/>
      <feFuncG type="linear" slope="[amount]"/>
      <feFuncB type="linear" slope="[amount]"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Checkout the **brightness(amount)** section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter

Comment: Is it still possible to make a transition between two filter states if I use this method?

Comment: I don't think so, is that an issue?

Comment: You can use the <animate> element to animate SVG filter values